# What does "reflect such" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can anybody explain **reflect such** and **cap** for me in this context?

"The corporate tax rate is likely cut in the first 100 days and other proposed major corporate tax code changes deferred. The time in-between inauguration and tax cuts is risky; waiting for stimulus when rates and FX markets **reflect such** will **cap** stocks."

Source: http://www.businessinsider.com/stock-market-outlook-for-2017-2016-12/#2300-bank-of-america-merrill-lynch-1

Comment: **such** is a pronoun, and so we must find its antecedent. The only candidate in the sentence is "stimulus".  The verb, "to cap", means to set an upper limit upon something, preventing it from rising any higher. Financial prognosticators are not famous for the clarity of their statements. **Reflect** is hardly the ideal verb there.

Comment: so does it mean "waiting for rates and FX markets to reflect stimulus will cap stocks"?

Comment: To paraphrase: *Waiting for stimulus when rates and FX markets reflect stimulus* will prevent stocks from rising further.  I am not going to guess what the author might have meant in the italicized phrase.    But *when rates and FX markets reflect stimulus* is a condition that exists during the "waiting", not a future outcome of the waiting, in that sentence structure.